# C# Simple encryption for application password?

Tags: c#, encryption

For my application I would like to store passwords and obviously encrypt them. From what I can gather I need one way encryption with salt? My plan is to save the password to the DB once they create an account. Doing so I create a salt and with that then create a hash. When they go to log in I then take the stored salt and take the entered value and loop through each of the credentials re-encrypting it with the stored salt and seeing if it matches the stored hash? Am I correct in doing it this way because each time run the encryption is different from the stored encryption. Below are my salt and encryption methods. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
public string CreateSalt(string UserName)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(UserName, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("seaaSalt"), 10000);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.GetBytes(25));
    }

    public string HashPassword(string Salt, string Password)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes Hasher = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password,
            System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Salt), 10000);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Hasher.GetBytes(25));
    }
```

Comment: Ideally you will have one salt key against which you will encrypt or decrypt stored values in your Database. What is your database? SQL provides column level encryption as well.

Comment: What do you mean by looping through the credentials? Why is the password not enough? Also, why are you using `UserName` to get a salt?

Comment: @Rob May I know what is the concern when creating salt based on username?

Comment: @active92 Because a salt should be cryptographically random, ideally. Also, on second look, it appears `CreateSalt` is merely hashing the username - not creating a salt.

Comment: The salt is there to prevent precomputation attacks, including Rainbow tables. The salt value should not be calculated based on a username or any constant value. Use random data instead. Then save the salt in a separate database column, or you can store it in the password column by appending the salt value to the hashed password value using a delimiter character.

Comment: And yes, this is one-way calculation. Once the user logs on, you just take the salt (which was used to calculate the stored password hash) from the database. And then, using that salt, you just calculate a hash value again to check if it matches the hash value in the database. If it does, the user is considered authenticated.

Comment: So are these methods incorrect? As I have done as @Vitaly has said.

Comment: @RainMan your _CreateSalt_ method will return the same string each time you run it for a given user. Change your _CreateSalt_ method to the following: `byte[] bytes = new byte[SALT_LENGTH_CONST]; RandomNumberGenerator rnd = RandomNumberGenerator.Create(); rnd.GetBytes(bytes); return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);`

Comment: So why does my encryption method return a different hash each time even if I use the same salt? @ Vitaly

Comment: @RainMan just tested your `HashPassword` method. On my system it returns the same hash if I use the same salt argument (using the same password of course). You can check it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BNcOQ3) (I had to decrease the number of iterations to make it work online though).